# How to get only the rows user has access in Dynamodb using batch get item?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

I'm trying to protect some rows of a DynamoDB table based on the key. I can accomplish it using the *dynamodb:LeadingKeys* condition.
It works if I make a single GetItem query. However I have several rows to load/check for access, and want to query for all of them at once, and receive only the rows the user has access.

For instance have the following table in Dynamo:

`AccessType | Key
 public     | A
 private    | B`

Using the following policy:

```
 {
        "Sid": "RestrictPrivate",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
            "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
            "dynamodb:GetItem",
            "dynamodb:ListTables",
            "dynamodb:Query",
            "dynamodb:Scan"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:dynamodb:REGION:ACC:table/keys"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                    "public"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

It works for a single row query:

> Query for key=A - Returns ok
>
> Query for key=B - Returns AccessDeniedException

But it is slow, i'd like to make a bulkgetitem and only get the rows I have access, however if the bulkgetitem results contains one denied row, it will fail entirely.

Is there a way to query for multiple rows containing allowed and disallowed rows, returning only the allowed ones with one request?

Comment: Where are ids for batch get are coming from? Instead of trying filter items with batch get, is it possible to pre-filter them before and only get items you have access to?

Comment: Suppose I have the ids, so I need o check for the current user which rows he has access based on these ids.
So I know there is key A and key B, i want to check which ones i can access, problem is that I need to check each one individually, not all of them together.